# Sending Videos from Twilio

Tags: video, twilio, mms

Is it possible to reliably send MMS videos from Twilio? I've attempted to send .mp4's and have had mixed results per carrier and device. Twilio's documentation says nothing about video but does say images work well across all devices.

Am I missing something about videos? Does anyone know of a cellular service provider MMS compatibility matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was actually able to get this to work 100% of the time (in my testing at least) by using files under 500kb. Anything larger seemed to have mixed results.

I also seemed to have missed this page (https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/logs) within my account. Clicking on the DateTime stamp will provide more detailed error messaging.

Answer (score 2):

Joe, Megan from Twilio here. Video is not explicitly *supported* for [MMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). It is *accepted*, meaning requests will not be rejected, but content will not be modified for device compatibility.

You can see a full list of [accepted content types here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types#sts=Video).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Megan. Do you know if a device/carrier compatibility list for mms video messages exists?

Comment: Hello @megan-speir, how do you send a video over text message please?